# mysql use of index in WHERE and in GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

This is about a many-to-many table linked either side to tables with about 70000 records each.  The many-to-many has about 5.3 million records.

There are foreign key references to both "side" tables (one is "tokens", the other is "paras").  To find out all the paras containing a given token, I need to do a SELECT statement along the lines of

```
SELECT para_id FROM many_to_many WHERE token_id = 3333 GROUP BY para_id;
```

This seems to be operating quite slowly despite the fact that the "token_id" column is the "leftmost" column of a composite primary key, and that there is an index (used by the para_id foreign key) on para_id.

I've tried to use EXPLAIN but this never seems to mention using the para_id index.  My question is: is it possible to get MySQL to use the para_id index?  If not, would it be possible to get it to use the index (on 'ID') of table "paras", if I included a "JOIN paras ON paras.ID = many_to_many.para_id" in the query?  Would this be likely to lead to a performance improvement?

Comment: Please post the table's structure and the `EXPLAIN` output.

Comment: Why are you using `GROUP BY` in a query with no aggregate functions? I'd wager that `SELECT DISTINCT` would work better in this case.

Comment: @Sammitch - ah, makes sense.  Thanks very much, I'll explore this.  Maybe you should put in an answer if you care about points, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to index `many_to_many` by `token_id` field.  Composite primary key does not help here.

Comment: thanks... I have read that in fact a composite primary functions like a normal single-field index, but only for the left-most element in the composite primary (token_id in this case).  But your suggestion makes me think I should do some experiments nonetheless...